# Install Rails in Godaddy domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-hosting

I am rails developer and I own a domain in godaddy. i dont want to install wordpress for this site. i just want to create this site with rails. As far as i searched i found it hard to run rails on a godaddy domain. But i dont have a clear idea.
As i am create this site fresh i dont have any database migration and such stuffs. Just trying to start developing the site from scratch, (already have a application in local need to deploy that in godaddy). Any help would be highly helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Rails had nothing to do with the domain it's a framework, just point the DNS to your web server and you are good to go.

Comment: Kiloreux is correct unless you are using Godaddy hosting? In that case I would recommend you stop what you're doing and research Heroku

Comment: You are not going to be able to upload your files like a php app and call it good, rails has more complicated dependencies. Heroku or Digital Ocean are a good idea.

Comment: kiloreux.. i am not getting you correctly can u suggest some links..

Thanks penner.. sign up for Heroku and deployed my first app. But still i have a hosting plan in godaddy and doesnt want to waste that..

Answer (score 1):

For a Rails app, the [shared hosting product](https://www.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting.aspx) GoDaddy offers isn't going to offer a new enough version of Ruby/Rails (Ruby is 1.8.7, which I think you can only use Rails 2.3.8)

Your best bet might be to try the new Cloud Servers product:
https://www.godaddy.com/pro/cloud-servers

You can create/destroy/backup VMs via [REST API calls](https://developer.godaddy.com/) if you wanted to or just simply use the UI they provide. The low-end plan is $5/month USD, but you can upgrade if your app needs it